# CMake and CTest: automatically run test's dependencies

Tags: c++, c, testing, cmake, ctest

In my CMakeLists.txt I have something like this:

```
 set_property(TEST testX APPEND PROPERTY DEPENDS testY)
 set_property(TEST testX APPEND PROPERTY DEPENDS testZ)
```

And I want some way to run `testX` and all its dependencies automatically.
Something like:

```
ctest <options> testX
```

and as a result, CTest will run `textY`, `testZ` and `testX`.
Is there any way to do this?

Or, if it is impossible now, is there any way to extract information on the dependencies from the CMake build directory by script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no built-in way of doing this as far as I know.

The best way I can think of to achieve your goal is to use the [`LABELS` property](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.3/prop_test/LABELS.html) on the tests.  You can retrieve the list of dependencies using [`get_property`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.3/command/get_property.html) or [`get_test_property`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.3/command/get_test_property.html) and apply the same label to `testX` and each of its dependent tests:

```
get_test_property(testX DEPENDS DependenciesOfTestX)
set_tests_properties(testX ${DependenciesOfTestX} PROPERTIES LABELS LabelX)
```

Then you can tell CTest to only run tests with that label:

```
ctest -L LabelX
```

Answer (score 5):

Support for test fixtures was added in CMake 3.7 and they do exactly what you want. Your particular scenario would be implemented like this:

```
set_property(TEST testX PROPERTY FIXTURES_REQUIRED Foo)
set_property(TEST testY PROPERTY FIXTURES_SETUP Foo)
set_property(TEST testZ PROPERTY FIXTURES_SETUP Foo)
```

You can then ask `ctest` to run just `testX` and it will automatically add `testY` and `testZ` to the set of tests to be executed:

```
ctest -R testX
```

It will also ensure that `testX` will only run after `testY` and `testZ` have been passed. If either of `testY` or `testZ` fails, `testX` will be skipped. New options `-FS`, `-FC` and `-FA` were also added to `ctest` in CMake 3.9 which allow automatic adding fixture setup/cleanup tests to be controlled at the `ctest` command line. For example, to temporarily skip adding `testY` to the test set but still automatically add `testZ`, one could do this:

```
ctest -R testX -FS testY
```

The fixtures properties are described in the CMake [docs](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_test/FIXTURES_REQUIRED.html) and the following article covers the fixtures feature more comprehensively:

https://crascit.com/2016/10/18/test-fixtures-with-cmake-ctest/